# Windows does not detect my hard drive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hard-drive-failure, hardware-detection

my hard drive (WD Scorpio Blue 1TB) is not recognized by my Windows 7. The hard drive spins but it clicks every 2-3 minutes and is not recognized by windows using sata to usb cable and sata only. I have a software to recover my data in case the hard drive is detected but I can't get it to sho on that software. I even tried with a live cd but it didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That dosen't sound good, and it sounds like you're unlucky enough to have had two different failure modes at once.

The drive not being detected indicates there's an issue with either the cable or the logic board. Considering that you've tried a USB adaptor, we may be able to rule out the cable. The 'brains' of your HDD seem to have fried. I had one of those infamous segates which first started erroring out (did yours?) then dying.

The clicking is the dreaded [click of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death) - thats your hard drive trying to recover from errors. Since the hard drive isn't detected, this might also be related to the other issue, but might also mean physical head damage. If the drive is under warranty, I strongly recommend RMAing it. There's very little you can do.

Comment: It is still in garanty but they just give you a new one without even try to repair it. I have a lot of projects there that cost me tons of hours but it is not worth to pay 1200 euros to get all the information. Any linux based live cd I can try?

Comment: I have had luck with Hdd Regen http://www.dposoft.net/ with hdds that click  even if windows can not see them. BUT the hdd must be seen from bios. If it does not even show up in bios there is no point to try it. Using Hdd Regen takes a long time (24+ hrs if its really bad). That was with a hdd that was making click/scrapping sounds. Hdd Regen is not free, but I have recovered several hdds (work/friends/myself) with it. Not all of them, but a couple I thought were hopeless.

Comment: see if PartedMagic can see the hdd: http://partedmagic.com/doku.php

Comment: Just my 2cents. There's a point where DIY recovery stops being an option. The drive not being detected at all is a good place to decide 'there's only so much I can do'. Most recovery livecds use the same tools and well, they rely on being able to access the drive. Your options are really to decide if your work is worth 1200 euros, or to just get the drive RMAed. The non optional thing is to work out a backup stratergy that would work with you.

Answer (score 2):

If it's not detected by your computer's BIOS and/or not resonding to any disk commands then the only recourse would be to get a company with a clean room facility to recover the data.

Clicking is usually a sign that you wouldn't be able to get the data without engaging a data recovery company - usually too expensive to justify for a home user.

You might be lucky using a product to image the disk (like Quetek's Disk Recoup) or copying the data via their File Scavenger product. I was able to get data from a 'clicking' drive but it wasn't clicking that often - I imaged the disk and then retrieved the files from the image. The disk visible in the BIOS and while I couldn't see data in Windows Explorer the volume was still present in Disk Management.